# JQuery: Toggle hidden field's value

Tags: jquery

I've been searching for a while now on how to do this. In my form, I would like to toggle a value back and forth (true <-> false) by click a div.

How do you toggle a hidden field's true/false value using jquery?

---

```
<input id="myHiddenField" name="my[hidden_field]" type="hidden" value="false">

<a id="myDiv">Click Me</a>
```

I've tried

```
$('#myDiv').on('click'), (function() {
    var hiddenField = $('#myHiddenField'),
        val = hiddenField.val();

    hiddenField.val(val === "true" ? "false" : "true");
});
```

but nothing :(

jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/MV3A4/2/

Comment: Post supporting code here and show us what you have tried.

Comment: Hidden fields do not have boolean values, only strings.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/245062/whats-the-difference-between-javascript-and-java

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This is pretty straight forward. Add a click handler to your div, and update the value of your input using the val() method.

You haven't posted your markup, so I've used some placeholder ID's. You'll need to update those to selectors that work in your context:

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MV3A4/4/)**

```
$('#myDiv').on('click', function() {
    var hiddenField = $('#myHiddenField'),
        val = hiddenField.val();

    hiddenField.val(val === "true" ? "false" : "true");
});
```

Note that input values are always strings, so these won't be true booleans.

Comment: Still can't seem to get it to work. I've included a jsfiddle in my edit above

Comment: @Jon I updated my answer with a new demo. There were two issues with the fiddle: one I had an extra `(` character and two jQuery wasn't included in the fiddle.

Comment: I should've noticed those. Thank you

Comment: Still not working for me but since it's working fine in the jsfiddle, I'm assuming there's something going on in my code.. Thanks again

Comment: @Jon double check your selectors and make sure you wrap your jQuery code with `$(function (){...}`

Answer (score 2):

With just javascript:

```
document.getElementById('myClickableDiv').addEventListener('click',function(){
    var value =document.getElementById('myHiddenField').value();
    if(value === "true"){
        document.getElementById('myHiddenField').value = "false";
    }else{
        document.getElementById('myHiddenField').value = "true";
    }
};
```

Comment: Didn't work for me. I've included a jsfiddle in my edit

Answer (score 1):

The jQuery code you tried has an error, there should not be a right paren before 'click'